# How to make a standalone document with one equation?

Tags: equations, standalone

I was surprised to find that `standalone` package can not compile a document with an equation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} % not working!
F(V, T) = E(V) + D(T)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Is there an option or some workaround that allows this? The current error is something like:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

in line 4. (The idea of course is that the including (main) document can just `\input` the standalone without knowing if is going to be an equation or something else)

Comment: Its work in texlive2011 check it.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The 1.0 version of `standalone` changed the default option from `preview` to `crop`. The latter has several benefits for the use-case the author (me) deemed most common, but forces *restricted horizontal* mode, which doesn't allow for lists or paragraphs. This causes an error for certain environments which require these.

One easy way is to enable the `preview` mode manually by using it as a class option (`\documentclass[preview]{standalone}`). You can also reenable this option as default using the `standalone.cfg` file as described in the manual.
However, with `preview` you get a full line-wide PDF with the equation number (1) at the right, which is not really what you want, is it?

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} % works now!
F(V, T) = E(V) + D(T)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Instead it is better to use inline math mode using `$ .. $` or `\( .. \)`, which will work with `crop` and doesn't produce a full line nor a number. You can add `\displaystyle` if you need it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
F(V, T) = E(V) + D(T)
$
\end{document}
```

There is also the `varwidth` option which will wrap the content in a `varwidth` environment (`varwidth` package), which is a variable width `minipage`. This also allows for paragraph breaks etc. and might be better for multi-line equations. `varwidth` takes an option length argument as text width.

Comment: I actually have a `math` option in mind for `standalone`, but currently no time to implement it.

Comment: With the [preview] option now works! 1) yes, the horizontal mode must have been a dilemma. 2) Answering your question about the numbering can give you ideas on how to implement a math option in standalone: In the final/long document is likely that one wants the numbering (so one is forced to use the equation environment) but in the preview/standalone the numeration doesn't make any sense. So one can add the following to the preamble of the standalone `\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{{\ }}
\makeatother`
Something like this can be handled by your planned math option.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, I would like to see an `align` equation environment in your planned `math` option. Perhaps I'm being self-entitled, but hear out my use case:

I'm using `sympy` to output some LaTeX math code and `latexmk` to refresh a PDF viewer. I'm still starting out with using this kind of environment. My objective is to automate tedious symbolic mathematical manipulations, especially helpful for non-math majors who need to tangle with big math (engineers like me).

Or perhaps a full-blown math environment compatibility for standalone?

Comment: @MartinScharrer — Thanks for this great package! Is there any chance that you can add a note about this to the documentation? Currently, search for “math” does not give any results…

Comment: @MartinScharrer Is there any way to output to png with `math`? See [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1582448/convert-mathematical-formula-to-image-locally-on-linux/1582453#1582453).

Comment: Yes, `preview`+`varwidth` does exactly what I need: math formulas are displayed and the page is cropped to the content even horizontally. If the content is clipped (doesn't fit the page), I can set `varwidth=10000` and it is fully displayed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

`standalone` uses `preview` internally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

% if you need the equation number, remove the asterix
\PreviewEnvironment{equation*}

% if you need paddings, adjust the following
\PreviewBorder=0pt


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*} % remove the asterix if you need the equation number
F(V, T) = E(V) + D(T)
\end{equation*} % remove the asterix if you need the equation number
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand what I have to do. Even if I compile your equivalent code (based on preview) the equation is not really rendered as math but as text.

Comment: @alfC: You need to load `amsmath`. See my edit above.

Comment: Its work in texlive2011 check it.

Comment: @S.Murugan: It works with the `preview` option enabled. This is the case by default with v0.x, but no longer with v1.x as explain in my answer. A "original" TL2011 might still have v0.x, but an updated one has v1.0.

Comment: @DamienWalters: `standalone` only uses `preview` if the `preview` option is used, which is no longer the default in v1.0.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code with a slight adjustment. Instead of `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` I wrapped the equation with dollar symbols like this:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone} 
\begin{document}
$F(V_{x}, T, \sigma) = E(V_{x}) + D(T,\sigma)$
\end{document}
```

This compiles without error for me. It does not provide you with equation numbering though.