# algorithmicx crashes standalone

Tags: incompatibility, standalone, svg, algorithmicx

I am creating SVG files from different stuff from my LaTeX document. For this, I am using the `standalone` package followed by `pdf2svg`.

This compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Function {$foo$}{$id$}
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Using `standalone` instead of `article` crashes with:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8             \Function
                 {$foo$}{$id$}
```

What can I do? I need to export my algorithms to PDF/SVG.

My versions:

- standalone.cls    2012/05/20 v1.1a
- algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2

---

`UPDATE: 27.06.2012` The same is happening with `align`:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    a\\
    b
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The v-box hack helps:

```
\begin{document}
\vbox{
    \begin{align*}
    a\\
    b
    \end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put your algorithm into a `\vbox` also with `\setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}` as a ugly hack.

Comment: For reference, this does not happen with `standalone` on [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com): `2010/03/27 v0.3a` and the most current version of `algorithmicx`: `2005/04/27 v1.2`.

Comment: On windows 7 and texlive 2011, i get the same error as Dennis with `standalone`. Yes on ScribTex its working normally. Its surprising why this difference.

Comment: Why does the `\vbox`-hack works? The `setlength`-hack does not work for me.

Comment: Put the `setlength` command in your preamble after the package declarations to shorten the width. The reason for the functionality is that we hide the linebreaks and other complications into a box such that standalone just sees a box to be shown. And setlength helps to reduce the width of the box.

Comment: Of course `setlength` is working. By mistake I compiled an other file. Thanks for vbox/standalone clarification.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Can you please have a look at this?

Comment: Dennis, @percusse: Basically a duplicate of [How to make a standalone document with one equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50162)

Answer (score 6):

Use either the `preview` or the `varwidth` class option of `standalone`. As described in the manual the default is `crop` (not `preview`) since v1.0 and this does not support paragraphs or lists (and the mentioned environments are apparently based on lists).

Comment: Fyi: the manual for v1.1a says in the Introduction: `The class uses by default the preview package`

Comment: @Dennis: Mmm, maybe there is some old sentence somewhere. The description of the options however clearly states that `crop` is the default.

Comment: you're right. Because of that sentence I'm using crop so far. So I can just skip it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix doesn't work for me. Maybe because I'm also using a `class` class option? But when I use `\documentclass[preview, class=myclass]{standalone}`, I keep getting the error as above.

Comment: @Czechnology: Please provide a minimal working example which causes this error for you. You can post a follow-up question for this.