# Standalone package errors when creating table

Tags: tables, standalone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid paragraph due to trailing empty line in standalone file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/avoid-paragraph-due-to-trailing-empty-line-in-standalone-file)
>   [How to make a standalone document with one equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/how-to-make-a-standalone-document-with-one-equation)

Below is a MWE of a table that keeps outputting errors although it does display but not correctly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{An Tabl\'a Shiompal}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
\addlinespace
\toprule
A     & B     & C     & D \\
\midrule
1     & x     & j     & suas \\
2     & y     & k     & s\'ios \\
3     & z     & l     & deis \\
4     & u     & m     & cl\'e \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I replace `Standalone` with `article` it works ok. Am I missing something for the `standalone` usage?

Using TexnicCenter and MikTeX, latest versions.

Comment: Also related : [algorithmicx crashes standalone](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61281)

Comment: @percusse thanks for that. `[preview]` option with `standalone` fixes it. I was getting the same errors as in the 2nd link above