# How to export a table?

Tags: tables, png

I defined a table in LaTeX : `\begin{tabular}....\end{tabular}`.

Now i want to export that table to an image (PNG or something}.

It is possible? How can i do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so] site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to do that would be to enclose your tabular in a document, with the standalone class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{}

    \end{tabular}       

\end{document}
```

Then compile it with [dvipng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvipng/) or use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert the div into a png.

The credits go to [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible).

Comment: How can i get the dvipng?

Comment: Right [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvipng/)

Comment: Btw i m using MikTek in Windows 7

Comment: divpng is also available for windows. You could also use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php?ImageMagick=pip5vm3h8fosngiitf5jd4mak2#windows) to convert the div in an png. [Apparently](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=8997&page=23) MikTex has a program called dvipng.exe that converts dvi's to png's.

Comment: @Ricardo Please note the difference between `preview` and `crop` option of `standalone` package. More about it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63045/3235