# Need help going from LaTex to PNG

Tags: winedt, png

This is literally my first time using Latex, so although I found threads like [How to export a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63079/how-to-export-a-table) or [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible), I'm not sure where to find dvipng.exe.  I am using WinEdt8 if that helps.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
```

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
  Seed & Current System & n=5 & n=7 & n=9 \
  \hline
  1 & 25.00 & 15.63 & 22.26 & 29.03 \
  2 & 19.90 & 11.80 & 15.02 & 17.50 \
  3 & 15.60 & 9.27 & 10.74 & 11.47 \
  4 & 11.90 & 8.36 & 9.29 & 9.51 \
  5 & 8.80 & 6.64 & 6.73 & 6.31 \
  6 & 6.30 & 5.87 & 5.67 & 5.08 \
  7 & 4.30 & 5.19 & 4.77 & 4.06 \
  8 & 2.80 & 4.64 & 4.09 & 3.34 \
  9 & 1.70 & 4.06 & 3.40 & 2.65 \
  10 & 1.10 & 3.50 & 2.76 & 2.04 \
  11 & 0.80 & 3.27 & 2.53 & 1.83 \
  12 & 0.70 & 2.85 & 2.07 & 1.39 \
  13 & 0.60 & 2.54 & 1.77 & 1.15 \
  14 & 0.50 & 2.29 & 1.54 & 0.96 \
  Playoff Teams & 0.00 & 14.08 & 7.35 & 3.70 \
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

A very simple answer would be much appreciated

Comment: dvipng is on a Win8.1 system at C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin.    Another option is to compile to pdf, open the pdf, copy and paste image into powerpoint.  Now save as a png.  Ok for one time actions.  If you need to do this a lot then set up a user option in winedt to run dvipng on the current base filename after it has compiled a *.dvi file.

Comment: Perhaps, instead use `\documentclass[convert=true]{standalone}` which should convert the output (PS or PDF) to PNG by default. It requires the addition of `--shell-escape` and also having [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed.

Comment: Even though I only need this once for right now, I would like to be able to do this in the future.  I just installed Imagemagick, how do I add `--shell-escape`?

Comment: @R.Schumacher Can you steer me into how I set up a user option.  I have zero experience with LaTeX

Comment: @qwertylpc: I'm unfamiliar with the WinEd interface. However, in TeXnicCenter, under Build > Define Output Profiles, choose your compiler of choice (say LaTeX > PDF) and add `--shell-escape` to the "Command line arguments to pass to the compiler")

Comment: In WinEdt, go to Options -> Execution modes -> Console application, choose the accessory you're compiling with, and, in Switches, write `--shell-escape`

Comment: @Sterry how do I know which accessory I should compile with?  Also if I set this up, will I have to change it back to convert to PDF's in the future?

Answer (score 3):

If you upgrade to WinEdt 10, there's a plugin called [dvi2pic](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/dvi2pic.html) which lets you run dvipng from within WinEdt (TeX -> DVI menu).

First of all, use the `standalone` class and reduce your code to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
  Seed & Current System & n=5 & n=7 & n=9 \\
  \hline
  1 & 25.00 & 15.63 & 22.26 & 29.03 \\
  2 & 19.90 & 11.80 & 15.02 & 17.50 \\
  3 & 15.60 & 9.27 & 10.74 & 11.47 \\
  4 & 11.90 & 8.36 & 9.29 & 9.51 \\
  5 & 8.80 & 6.64 & 6.73 & 6.31 \\
  6 & 6.30 & 5.87 & 5.67 & 5.08 \\
  7 & 4.30 & 5.19 & 4.77 & 4.06 \\
  8 & 2.80 & 4.64 & 4.09 & 3.34 \\
  9 & 1.70 & 4.06 & 3.40 & 2.65 \\
  10 & 1.10 & 3.50 & 2.76 & 2.04 \\
  11 & 0.80 & 3.27 & 2.53 & 1.83 \\
  12 & 0.70 & 2.85 & 2.07 & 1.39 \\
  13 & 0.60 & 2.54 & 1.77 & 1.15 \\
  14 & 0.50 & 2.29 & 1.54 & 0.96 \\
  Playoff Teams & 0.00 & 14.08 & 7.35 & 3.70 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

At this point, run first latex and then dvipng.

The resulting png looks like:

[image]