# using standalone with algorithmicx or algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, standalone, algorithmicx

I am trying to compile a `standalone` file containing pseudocode created with the `algorithmicx` package.
According to [algorithmicx crashes standalone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61281/algorithmicx-crashes-standalone) it should work with the `preview` option set for standalone, however it does not.
Also the mentioned `vbox` hack does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

The first compiler error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox
l.13 \end{algorithm}
```

The (generic) pseudocode file:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\vbox{
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Sven

---

UPDATE:

Using the `algorithm2e` package (as suggested by David Carlisle) and not using the `vbox` lets the pseudocode file compile without errors.

When I use `\KwIn{foo}` it breaks again. This in turn is fixed by using `\usepackage[varwidth]{standalone}`. The pseudocode file compiles without errors.

However now when I try to include the pseudocode file in my main file, I get the following compilation error in the `algorithm2e.sty` when compiling the main file:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
&lt;argument&gt; \SetAlgoLined 

l.1177 ...etcount,titlenotnumbered,lined,shortend}
                                                  %
```

The new pseudocode file (without `~\\` there is no line break after `\KwIn{foo}`):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  ~\\
  \KwIn{foo}
  $r\gets a\bmod b$\;  
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The main file where pseudocode is included:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\include{pseudocode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've lost track a bit of the various packages but your example runs without error (with or without the `\vbox`) if you change

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

to

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```

Comment: That does work with the example I provided. However as soon as I use \KwIn{foo} it breaks again.

Answer (score 2):

It is the `algorithm` environment that breaks the whole thing. With only the `algorithmic` environment it does work.
So a workaround (albeit without the perks of `algorithm`) would be the following.

The file with the algorithm `pseudocode.tex`:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
  some introduction
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

The main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \input{pseudocode}
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The same should work with `algorithm2e`, I did not try that though.