# Compilation fails with eqnarray after reinstalling Miktex

Tags: math-mode, standalone

I have a script that extracts math formulae from a tex file, produces a
small standalone file for each formula and compiles it with pdflatex. The
standalone pdf files are then used to produce png images of the formulae.
The script has always worked smoothly with Miktex 2.8 under windows Vista.
Now that I have updated to version 2.9 and Windows 7, it does not work any
longer. Every time it encounters an eqnarray environment, it gives the
following error:

```
 ! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text>
                \endgroup
l.6 \begin{eqnarray}
```

For example, I get this error when I run pdflatex on the following simple
file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}   
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}    
1&=&1\\
1&=&1   
\end{eqnarray}    
\end{document}
```

Why am I getting this error? Has support for eqnarray been discontinued in
new versions of latex?

Thanks for any help you might provide.

Comment: There are empty lines in `eqnaarray` environment in your file. They generate errors.

Comment: sorry I removed the spaces that were not present in the original code. As I said everything worked in previous versions

Comment: Have you tried align? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why `standalone`? Does the same happen with `article`, or with `\documentclass[12pt,varwidth]{standalone}`?

Comment: works in both ways! why does it work with varwidth?

Comment: The reason it stopped working when you upgraded is that the default behaviour of `standalone` has changed in newer versions, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/how-to-make-a-standalone-document-with-one-equation