# Adding prefix to TikZ node and coordinate names

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices, tikzmark, hf-tikz

This question is somewhat related to my search for a [good practice to include TikZ stuff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212578/best-practice-for-including-standalone-commented-equations-with-tikz) in my documents.

Suppose a document (book) with a lot of formulas and equations which you have decorated with `TikZ` graphics, just to explain a step or to remark something. I'm using packages like [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark), [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) or even the way explained in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/arrow-between-parts-of-equation-in-latex/), which I think originated the `tikzmark` library.

The important thing is that each of these `TikZ` pieces is made by means of an `overlay`. So the coordinate (mark) names remain available through the full document and things only work if each name is **unique**.

I'd prefer to re-use A, B, C, etc. with name nodes and marks in every figure. So I wonder how to give a prefix before setting this marks, so A, B, C, etc. are appended to it (instead of having to write long expressions to uniquely identify each mark)

Comment: If you redefine them, you are done. Previous pages won't be affected.

Comment: I don't know why I was struggling with this... I'm checking and you're right.