# Problems with the standalone class when using certain environments and certain math symbols

Tags: standalone, grammar

I use TeX Live 2015.

*Update*. I just found out that using the `preview` option to the class solves the problem, yet only crops the content vertically, not horizontally.

I want to use a `grammar` environment from the `syntax` package within a `standalone` documentclass (for producing small images). But when I run `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{syntax}
\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}
<A> ::= `Z'
\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \end{grammar}
? 

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \end{grammar}
?
```

Of course, I can skip through them, but then my output becomes

[image: bad standalone output].

When I run the same code with the `standalone` class replaced by `minimal`, I get – without any errors – the expected output, viz:

[image: good minimal output]

So I have two issues:

1. How can I get the `standalone` class to work with the `grammar` environment?
2. How can I get the `standalone` class to correctly compile certain symbols like ‘<’ and ‘>’?

*By the way*. I realise I am misusing the `standalone` class. My use case is: Create small pictures out of latex code to include them on a website (where I don’t want to use MathJax). If you know of a good way to accomplish that, I’d be happy to give that a try instead.

Comment: i use `pdfcrop` for this, and gave the "formula" at [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247690/579](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247690/579).  there are other good answers to that question, so you might want to take a look.  regarding your second question, how to get `standalone` to "behave", i think the answer might be "don't use `standalone`.  i usually use `article`, and set `\pagestyle{empty}` to avoid headers and footers.

Comment: the output from `minimal` isn't really quite what is "expected".  the space following the `::=` is too tight.

Comment: Standalone does not define \textwidth, so always use a minipage for lists and equations.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Well, `standalone` processes the content as a single box not in vertical mode. So for vertical stuff, like paragraphs and equations a `minipage` or similar is indeed required. For this simply load the class with the `varwidth` option.

Comment: You need to use either the `preview` or the `varwidth` option if the content is paragraph material. See [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/how-to-make-a-standalone-document-with-one-equation/50171#50171) for further details.