# "You can't use `\eqno' in restricted horizontal mode. \end{equation}"

Tags: amsmath, tikz-cd

I'm going crazy with this error:

```
Bad math environment delimiter. \end{equation}
You can't use `\eqno' in restricted horizontal mode. \end{equation}
```

of the following `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[border=1 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
        \textbf{B} \arrow[r,"M"] & \text{Y}\\
        \textbf{X} \arrow[r,swap,"M"] \arrow[u,"project"] & \text{A} \arrow[u,"project", swap]
    \end{tikzcd}
\begin{equation}
    project \circ M = M \circ project
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need the equation to be numbered?

Comment: By substituting `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass[border=1 pt]{standalone}`, the error goes away.

Comment: @koleygr: It should be numbered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution here: [How to make a standalone document with one equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/how-to-make-a-standalone-document-with-one-equation)

Explanation: The `standalone` document class has no sections or structure and doesn't know which equation number to use. The `preview` option allows section and equation numbers.

Another solution would be to use custom centered inline math and custom number inside a tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,preview]{standalone} % <- Added "preview" option
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text macro
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
        \textbf{B} \arrow[r,"M"] & \text{Y}\\
        \textbf{X} \arrow[r,swap,"M"] \arrow[u,"\text{project}"] 
        & \text{A} \arrow[u,"\text{project}", swap]
    \end{tikzcd}

\begin{equation}
    \text{project} \circ M = M \circ \text{project} \tag{5.1} %<-If you dont want "(1)"
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```