# How to vertically wrapped page around formula?

Tags: geometry, scripts

thank you for your time.

I wonder if it is possible to render one phrase only in latex and make sure the document is wrapped around the phrase (no bigger that it need to be)? I know you can set the size of a document with the package `geometry` but I would prefer for it to be somewhat automatic as I want to incorporate this in a script.

example being the entire document: [image: this the entire document]
Thank you for you time and help

Comment: sounds like you are looking for the `standalone` documentclass. Can you post the code for your equation?

Comment: this is exactly that. Thank you, I had no clue such thing existed, I thought that latex was only an article like document maker. I(ve put your answer.

Comment: never underestimate the abilities of latex :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the comment from samcarter allowed me to find what I needed on the internet. The `standalone` document class is the one. This page has everything : [How to make a standalone document with one equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/how-to-make-a-standalone-document-with-one-equation).

Thank you

Even though the one in the link seems awfully similar to mine, I wont erase my question since to find the one in the link you have to know the `standalone` class (Unless asked otherwise of course). Good day to all.

*edit*:
As requested, here is the result
[image] 
from

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$
\displaystyle
\int_a^x f(t)dt = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x - a}{n} f\left(k \frac{x - a}{n} + a\right)
$
\end{document}
```

Notice the use of `$ \displaystyle ... $` instead of `$$ ... $$`; it is because the `standalone` class doesn't accept `$$` by default for being in crop mode. Going into preview mode only wrap the text vertically and not horizontally which is even better for me. If that is no problem for you however, just replace the line `\documentclass{standalone}` by `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}` from which the class allow the use of `$$`.

Comment: you should show us your solution ...

Comment: very well, I'll update immediately

Comment: even better, ask @samcarte that (s)he extend her/his comment to an answer ...

Comment: @S.lama Not necessary to ask me, I'm fine with you posting an answer yourself. As a improvement you could include a small sample document with the formula from your question.

Comment: @S.lama Nice answer! You might want to avoid `$$` altogether, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @samcarter and Zarko Thank you both, I have and will keep modifying my post as requested. Have a good day.