# ! Missing $ inserted. error

Tags: errors

I don't know why I'm getting

```latex
> ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11 m^
       *(E) := \inf_P m(P)
```

My code

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,esint}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
m^*(E) := \inf_P m(P)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can compile the code without problems.

Comment: Have used also the standalone class?

Comment: Yes. (although the error seems to be not related to `standalone`.) [My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mxbB.png).

Comment: `equation*` doesn't make sense in `standalone`.

Comment: My apologize, but I forgot I added `varwidth` option. Adding it will work.

Comment: As @egreg pointing out, you should replace your equation environment with a `\(` and `\)` or `$` and `$` (and posibly some `\displaystyle`s). Or you should use `preview`  optionb while loading the `documentclass`. Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50162/120578