# Latex-Workshop and Python Script

Tags: vscode, latex-workshop

I am trying to create a recipe to quickly generate a PNG from an equation in LaTeX. I wanted to use the existing `pdflatex` tool that is defined in the Latex-workshop recipes and then add an additional tool which converts the PDF to PNG and then moves it to a specific location I want the PNGs stored. I wrote a simple python script to convert the PDF to PNG, move the PNG, and then clean up the tex directory.

When I use the recipe I don't get any errors and it does create the PNG and clean up the files. But for some reason `mv` does not appear to be working and I am not sure why (the PNG is not moved).

Here are the `tools` I have defined

```
       {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-shell-escape",
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "Python Script to Generate PNG of Eqn",
            "command": "/usr/bin/python3",
            "args": [
                "MyPATH/MyScript.py",
                "%DOC%",
                "%OUTDIR%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        }
```

And here is the python script

```python
import os
import sys

tex_filename = sys.argv[1] 
tex_file_directory = sys.argv[2] 

os.system(f'convert -background white -alpha remove -density 600 {tex_filename}.pdf {tex_filename}.png')

# Move the png to my storage directory
MyPngLoc = 'PATH/TO/MY/PNG/FILES'
os.system(f'mv {tex_file_directory}/{tex_filename}.png {MyPngLoc}/{tex_filename}.png')

# Clean up tex directory
os.system(f'rm {tex_file_directory}/*.aux {tex_file_directory}/*.log {tex_file_directory}/*.pdf {tex_file_directory}/*.synctex')
```

And finally here is the recipe.

```
       {
            "name": "equation PDF ➞ PNG",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "Python Script to Generate PNG of Eqn"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use [the `standalone` class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50162/174620) with [the convert option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11880/174620) and use [the cool automation tool, arara](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara) which is native to TeX for [cleaning the aux files](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1932#a2166) and [moving the generated files to the desired folder (p. 134)](https://texdoc.org/serve/arara/0)?

Comment: The usual way to rename a file in python is to use `os.rename` or `shutil.move`. For example, see https://python.omics.wiki/file-operations/file-commands/os-rename-vs-shutil-move

Comment: @3141592653589793238 Thank you! I switched to `os.rename` and also realized that `%DOC%` should be `%DOCFILE%`. Now it works as intended.