# Render display math properly in Standalone environment

Tags: standalone, displaystyle

I am attempting to use latex to generate images of mathematical equations using the standalone environment. I wish to force the subscript and superscript to appear below and above the sum respectively in the manner of the following.
[image]
However, my code currently produces.
[image]
My code is as follows.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\definecolor{byellow}{RGB}{255, 255, 0}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\textcolor{byellow}
\[\displaystyle\pbm{\bm{\zeta \left(z\right) = {\sum}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{n}^{s}}}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the pair of braces around `\sum`? Also, \displaystyle is not necessary in a displayed equation.

Comment: @Bernard the issue is not extra braces (although, yes, they are redundant). standalone environment redefines equation environment, so you need inline math and a manual `displaystyle`. See my answer.

Comment: In this case, another suggestion: try with `\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}`.

Comment: About the math consistence itself: [Riemann's zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) is normally written as `\zeta(s)` instead of `\zeta(z)`, `s` is the variable inside the `sum` over `n`. I know both `z`and `s` are used as complex variables, but I must immediately ask when I see some inconsistency. Sorry for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no option, `standalone` uses *horizontal mode*: basically you have to think that the document body is typeset in a `\mbox`.

Indeed, your code produces errors. First error, `\[` is taken as argument to `\textcolor`, which wants *two* arguments. Second error: `! Missing $ inserted.` which is typical for `\[...\]` inside `\mbox`.

You can use `$\displaystyle...$` instead.

If you want the formula to be bold, *don't* use `\bm` nor `\pmb` (the latter makes for very dubious output). Simply issue `\boldmath`. The summation symbol would not be bold, though.

You can fix it by declaring the bold version for `cmex`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\definecolor{byellow}{RGB}{255, 255, 0}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}{<-> cmexb10}{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{cmex}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}%<--- don't forget
\color{byellow}%<--- don't forget
\boldmath
$\displaystyle\zeta(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the two font declarations you'd get

[image]

so you see that in the previous image the summation symbol is indeed bold.

For a further comparison, here's the output if `\boldmath` is omitted.

[image]

And also the output of the summation without the font declarations and using `\pmb`: not really what I'd like to see in my document.

[image]

Note that I removed several parts from your code: mainly `\left` and `\right` that only add unwanted space; also some braces that ruin the typesetting. And `s` instead of `z`.

Comment: Good as ever! My own personal preference, since this is a personal project where you can use any fonts and packages you want, would be to use modern fonts and `unicode-math`. The `\boldmath` (or `\boldsymbol{...}`) commands will still work, and you can `\setmathfont[bersion=bold, FakeBold=1.2]` if desired.

Answer (score 5):

`minipage` can restore the display style.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{black}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{26mm}
\color{yellow}\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\[
\zeta (z) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}
\]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use inline math with manual `\displaystyle` in `standalone` document class.

`standalone` class seems to redefine equation environment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50171/97712 .

Here is your MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\definecolor{byellow}{RGB}{255, 255, 0}

\begin{document}

    \pagecolor{black}
    \color{byellow}
    
    $\displaystyle
        \bm{
            \zeta \left( z \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^s }
        }
    $
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\definecolor{byellow}{RGB}{255, 255, 0}

\begin{document}

    \pagecolor{black}
    \color{byellow}
    
    $\displaystyle
        \bm{
            \zeta \left( z \right) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^s }
        }
    $
    
\end{document}
```