# Including a TikZ picture in an equation throws error with standalone class

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, pdftex, standalone

I'm trying to put a TikZ picture inside an equation, and then turn that into a standalone image using the "standalone" class. Representative but meaningless MWE below:

```
% This compiles but gives me an entire page
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}

% This is what I want to do.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \enspace = \enspace \exp(5)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However, this gives me a lot of errors related to missing `$`s or `\endgroup`s in maths mode, e.g. `Missing $ inserted. \end{tikzpicture}`.

Can anyone help me fix these errors? This compiles perfectly fine in an article (I'm trying to extract a standalone image from an existing document I've written). Worst case I'll just screenshot my document but I'd like the vector graphics!

Comment: Don't use `equation` in standalone. Use `tikzpicture` directly. Do you really need the equation number?

Comment: It's not about the equation number, the figure I'm making is basically "tikz picture = maths = tikz picture". I was actually going to use equation* in the final version but forgot to do that in the MWE.

Comment: Do you actually need TikZ for this? There is for example `\lefthalfcup` from the MnSymbol package which produces such a symbol

Comment: You can also put the equation inside a minipage.  I doubt varwidth will do anything to  help; as equations fill the entire width.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the two TikZ diagrams are much more complicated than this MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variant with equation

#### Adaptations

- use option `preview` for standalone (see [How to make a standalone document with one equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50162/123129))
- import tikz with `\usepackage{tikz}` (or `\documentclass[tikz, preview]{standalone} \standaloneenv{equation}`, see comment below)

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \enspace = \enspace \exp(5)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Variant without equation

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \(\displaystyle
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \enspace = \enspace \exp(5)
   \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Only thing is the image is full-width - do you know how I can ensure it crops horizontally as well as vertically?

Comment: +1 You can have `tikz` in the options, but then you need to add `equation` as a standalone env. `\documentclass[tikz, preview]{standalone}
\standaloneenv{equation}`

Comment: It is full width because the equation is. Don't use equation if you don't want that.

Comment: @Jared: That is what the `equation` does! So maybe you just want `displaystyle` math.

Comment: I added a variant without equation, so it is fully croped.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the displaystyle variant is exactly what I wanted.