# Arbitrary size pages

Tags: verbatim, paper-size

Is it possible to create a latex document where some pages have a unique size [width & depth] that basically is the right size to contain all the data from some input file?

**More details.** I am writing a technical document where I want to include very large tables (both in width and depth.) In order for me to edit these tables efficiently I don't use a latex environment such as `array` or `tabular`. Instead I produce tables such as the one below (this is a small subset of such a table) which I can conveniently resize etc ... using e.g. [`tablemode`](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode) in vim.

```
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Row   | Persp. |                                     |                                     |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i     | SCEN   | SCEN/MODEXP                         | FAILURE_KNOWN_TO_RAM                |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i + 1 | MISC   | MMU_FLAG = 0                        | EXP_FLAG = 0 blablablablablablabla  | OOB_FLAG = 1      blablablablablablablablablablabla      |
```

My strategy is to include these tables *as is* in my main document by putting the above text inside of a `verbatim` environment.

What I would like to do is have some pages of arbitrary size that can precisely fit such tables. Outside of these pages the document should be standard A4 pages.

Comment: Have you considered the standalone class for your tables?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz As in produce a standalone document, compile it and include the pdf? I have not tried it. The only reason being that I don't want to the recompilation by hand every time. But this does seem like a good option.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried your suggestion. It seems I have to add the `preview` option for it to compile (as suggested here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/how-to-make-a-standalone-document-with-one-equation). But the pdf is cropped for some reason. I.e. it produces a pdf which has the right depth but not the right width.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this: https://pastebin.com/furBjeGs

Comment: That is **precisely** the output I was looking for :D Thank you

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be to compile the tables using the `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen,margin=0.5cm,multi={verbatim}]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Row   | Persp. |                                     |                                     |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i     | SCEN   | SCEN/MODEXP                         | FAILURE_KNOWN_TO_RAM                |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i + 1 | MISC   | MMU_FLAG = 0                        | EXP_FLAG = 0 blablablablablablabla  | OOB_FLAG = 1      blablablablablablablablablablabla      |
\end{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Row   | Persp. |                                     |                                     |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i     | SCEN   | SCEN/MODEXP                         | FAILURE_KNOWN_TO_RAM                |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i + 1 | MISC   | MMU_FLAG = 0                        | EXP_FLAG = 0 blablablablablablabla  | OOB_FLAG = 1      blablablablablablablablablablabla      |
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you intend to include the text twice ?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat yes, to show the each table will automatically create a new page and since there was only one example table in the question, I used it twice :)

Comment: On a different note: do you happen to know how to include emojis into verbatim text ? My original text actually includes symbols à la  (in lue of `_FLAG`) but these don't render properly.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705376/including-emojis-in-verbatim

Comment: So is your suggestion to produce these standalone pdf's and then to include them in the main document via `\includepdf` ?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Yes. Depending on your compilation workflow, one might even be able to automate the creation of the pdf with all the tables.