# Including emojis in verbatim

Tags: verbatim, emoji

This is a follow-up question to [this one on arbitrary size pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705370/arbitrary-size-pages).

How would one include emojis in a verbatim environment?

E.g.

```
\begin{verbatim}
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Row   | Persp. |                                     |                                   |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i     | SCEN   | SCEN/MODEXP                         | FAILURE_KNOWN_TO_RAM              |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i + 1 | MISC   | MMU = 0                           | EXP = 0                         | OOB = 1                                                |
\end{verbatim}
```

Produces the following
[image]

**Edit.** I get errors when running the proposed solution:
[image]
Row 5 in my file contains

```
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
```

Hm. I guess `tectonic` has limited support of `lualatex`, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tectonic.

```
oob/populating/modexp on  boulot [$!?] 
❯ cat representation.log 
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)  (format=lualatex 2023.12.20)  20 DEC 2023 16:00
 restricted system commands enabled.
**representation.tex
(./representation.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-12-11>
Lua module: luaotfload 2023-08-31 3.26 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-08-19.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-
2023-08-19.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.133
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/local/texlive/202
3/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count186
\c@sapage=\count187

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box51
\sift@deathcycles=\count196
\@vwid@loff=\dimen140
\@vwid@roff=\dimen141
)
\sa@box=\box52
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-12-11 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-11-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count197
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box53
))
Package: xparse 2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2022/01/15 2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (/
usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen142
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen143
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen144

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script latn
luaotfload | aux : font no 18 (nil) defines no feature for script dflt

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoMono/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoMono/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoMono/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoMono(0)' created for font 'Noto Mono'
(fontspec)             with options
(fontspec)             [WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=Word
Space,RawFeature={fallback=emojifallback}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoMono:mode=node;language=dflt;fallback=emojifallb
ack;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 


(./representation.aux)
\openout1 = representation.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
6.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/NotoMono(0)/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/NotoMono(0)/b/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 66.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∨ (U+2228) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∨ (U+2228) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∨ (U+2228) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
Missing character: There is no ∧ (U+2227) in font NotoMono:mode=node;language=
dflt;fallback=emojifallback;!
</tmp/lua_jXG30F>] (./representation.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-12-11>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 3712 strings out of 476506
 244175,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec,
 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:620,3:13264,4:2,5:4283,6:149,7:22199,8:1,9:469,11:135
 25733 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 33 fonts using 3140863 bytes
 79i,5n,89p,249b,231s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoMono-Regular.ttf>
Output written on representation.pdf (1 page, 18378 bytes).

PDF statistics: 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

The symbol between `bbs` and `mbs` should be a vee:
[image]

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen,margin=0.5cm,multi={verbatim}]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("emojifallback",
    {
      "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmonofont{Noto Mono}[
  RawFeature={fallback=emojifallback}
]

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Row   | Persp. |                                     |                                   |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i     | SCEN   | SCEN/MODEXP                         | FAILURE_KNOWN_TO_RAM              |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i + 4 | MISC   | MMU = extract_raw_mbs             | EXP = trim_raw_mbs              | OOB = extract_raw_mbs                                  |
|       |        |                                     |                                   |                                                          |
|       |        | MMU_INST = MLOAD, offset = cdo + 64 | EXP_INST = trimBytesBeyond        | (implicit check) mbs ≤ 512                               |
|       |        |                                     |                                   | OOB_INST = MODEXP_modulus                                |
|       |        |                                     |                                   | max_bbs_mbs := bbs ∨ mbs                                 |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With Jet Brains Mono I get an error:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the brilliant answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/36296 and choose a fallback font which has your emoji. If you want to use them in verbatim text, you'll need to set the mono font instead of the main font:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen,margin=0.5cm,multi={verbatim}]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("emojifallback",
    {
      "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono NL Regular}[
  RawFeature={fallback=emojifallback}
]

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Row   | Persp. |                                     |                                   |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i     | SCEN   | SCEN/MODEXP                         | FAILURE_KNOWN_TO_RAM              |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i + 4 | MISC   | MMU = extract_raw_mbs             | EXP = trim_raw_mbs              | OOB = extract_raw_mbs                                  |
|       |        |                                     |                                   |                                                          |
|       |        | MMU_INST = MLOAD, offset = cdo + 64 | EXP_INST = trimBytesBeyond        | (implicit check) mbs ≤ 512                               |
|       |        |                                     |                                   | OOB_INST = MODEXP_modulus                                |
|       |        |                                     |                                   | max_bbs_mbs := bbs ∨ mbs                                 |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(to find out which fonts on your system have the emoji, you can use the command line tool albatross using this command: `albatross` )

Comment: Thanks. I get errors when compiling the above, see updated question. Also I don't have albatross on my system (Ubuntu) and it's not known to `apt` (i.e. `sudo apt install albatross` fails.)

Comment: You need to compile with `lualatex`. Albatross is part of texlive. If you have a complete texlive installation, it is automatically included.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat albatross is not installed by apt as part of `texlive-full` (it is probably part of a full install with vanilla TeX Live though). However you can download the jar file at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/albatross/scripts and then it works out of the box on Ubuntu with `java -jar albatross.jar ` for example.

Comment: When I try compiling it it doesn't produce a pdf. There are no associated errors, but the process doesn't seem to finish.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Can you show your .log file?

Comment: See edit please.

Comment: I have some `∨` and `∧` characters, too. These seem to be causing the issue.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat It seems it cant find the emoji font. Do you have Noto Color Emoji installed on your computer?

Comment: How would I check ?

Comment: ... wait a sec, I might have read the error message wrong

Comment: BTW: this also fails when I remove the rows containing the aforementioned characters.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Can you show your whole log file?

Comment: I included it. It's for the truncated file (i.e. after removing the `∨` and `∧` characters

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Texlive 2019 seems to be too old

Comment: I'm not sure if I have texlive to be honest, see newest screenshot. I can find `texliveonfly` but not `texlive`

Comment: @OlivierBégassat You do have texlive, see second line in your log: `TeX Live 2019/Debian`

Comment: Yes, my bad. When trying to install it it tells me

```
❯ sudo apt install texlive
[sudo] password for olivier: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive is already the newest version (2019.20200218-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Comment: @OlivierBégassat The texlive versions included in linux are often very outdated. If you would like an up-to-date one, you can install it from https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: I'm following the installation of the new version of texlive. It's rather slow (currently I'm at: Installing [1550/4624, time/total 6:30/19:27]

Comment: @OlivierBégassat That sounds rather fast :) Depending on the network it can take hours :)

Comment: I guess I'll come back to you in 15 minutes or so when it's done (hopefully ^^) Let me thank you already for your help : ) Current status: Installing [2044/4624, time/total: 08:44/20:53]: imtekda [646k]

Comment: @OlivierBégassat have fun watching all the package names fly by :)

Comment: Ok ^^ it's done. I'll try to build it again

Comment: It worked  For some reason it takes rather long to compile but I'll take it : ) **Edit** There is still an issue: the wedges and vees aren't represented correctly. But for some reason it didn't complain during compilation

Comment: @OlivierBégassat yeah! (on the first run, it needs to set up a cache for the fonts etc., it might me a bit faster in the future)

Comment: I don't get it ^^ how can emoji's work but wedges and vees not ^^ I'll add the new log file to my question.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Please add a test file with the problematic characters

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Same as with the emoji: Use albatross to find a font which has these characters. Or could probably choose whatever font you use in your terminal.

Comment: I added the source code as an answer (to avoid editing my question too often)

Comment: BTW: albatross ∨ now produces some output

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Please don't use answers for additional information.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Is there any monospaced font among the albatross output?

Comment: Many, see screenshot in answer.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Oh, great you have jet brains. Then the updated code from my answer should work.

Comment: It doesn't accept Jet Brains for some reason ... see latest screenshot

Comment: But it does accept it if I put `NF` rather than `NL` : )

Comment: Finally : ) Thank you so much !

Comment: @OlivierBégassat You're very welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Simple version that works with XeLaTeX, using `fancyvrb` with `Verbatim` (instead of lower case `verbatim`) to run a command `\emj` that changes the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,left=5mm,right=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\emj}[1]{{\fontspec{Symbola}#1}}
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| Row   | Persp. |                                     |                                   |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i     | SCEN   | SCEN/MODEXP                         | FAILURE_KNOWN_TO_RAM              |                                                          |
|-------+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------|
| i + 1 | MISC   | MMU\emj{ } = 0                           | EXP\emj{ } = 0                         | OOB\emj{ \,\,} =         1                                       |
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that switching the font disturbs the monospace so you need some tricks with extra spaces or whitespace commands like `\,` to align the bars - this would also be needed with the LuaLaTeX solution in the other answer. Note also that the flag in Symbola is ugly but that is not really the point :)